# JavaScript to find the length of an object

Tags: javascript

I have a response object .

I am trying to check the length of it using below code:

```
 var count = Object.keys(response).length;
```

however it is showing count 17 ideally i think,it should show 1.

i am returning "email" object as a response.

[image]

any idea on this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "response Object"? It looks to me that your response object is a string, so of course the "length" of it is the number of characters in the string.

Comment: What does "typeof response" return? It does not look like an object. You are getting string length instead of array length...

Comment: any idea how to get the count as 1 instead of length of the string?

Comment: Why do you want a length of 1 from that data? What value would lead you to want something other than 1?

Comment: Actually I am returning on the basis of condition.if condition one is true it should return an object i.e email only one field and if its is false it should return an object containing more than one fields .so just trying to check which one is returned  using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can get the length of an object (here `response`) by simply doing this:

```
var count = response.length;
```

But `response` is actually not an object in your example, but a string. So `length` returns the number of characters in the string, here 17.

Comment: any idea how to get the count as 1 instead of length of the string?

Comment: To do this, `response` needs to be an object. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are going for, but response is 17 characters, you are asking for the length of the response. It's an `array` of characters essentially.

for clarity.

```
var response = "'test1@gmail.com'";
var count = Object.keys(response).length;
```

`.keys` returns the enumerable properties of an object, The object `response` is a string, or a "series" of `char`.

It goes to stand then that the length of the object is `17`.

You may be looking for, and this may work

```
Object.keys(response.Data).length;
```

**UPDATED**
Here is the answer OP is looking for. Can't make a comment.

```
var response = {response: "'email@email.com'"};


var count = Object.keys(response).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: any idea how to get the count as 1 instead of length of the string?

Comment: @ChrisClark . I tried however its showing count undefined.

Comment: @Harshit You haven't provided any information on how response is used, created etc. You will not be able to use your existing code for response. Please update your question, and in the future use as much information as you can. My guess is response is undefined, because you never modified your existing code to insert into an object

Answer (score 1):

And if you place any other string with a different length you will get a different result

```
Object.keys("hello").length
>> 5
```

In you example the function counts the length of the response string, not the keys of an object.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Because a string is enumerable `Object.keys` returns you the length of the, it (mistakenly?) counts each character as a key using a plain for `loop`.

Comment: any idea how to get the count as 1 instead of length of the string?

Comment: count of what ? Object.keys should be used with plain objects